# Use 'ant clean test' with the newest android sdk. '${renderscript.opt.level}' is not a permitted value for com.android.ant.RenderScriptTask$OptLevel

Tags: android, ant

Use 'ant clean test' with the newest android sdk got error:

build.xml:622: The following error occurred while executing this line:

build.xml:642: 
'${renderscript.opt.level}' is not a permitted value for com.android.ant.RenderScriptTask$OptLevel

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How's this? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-974 Seems to be an issue in R20 of the Android SDK API 16 (the latest as of June 28, 2012). I've actually no experience with RenderScript but the solution appears to be setting `renderscript.opt.level=O0`.

Comment: Hi tom, set that where? in ant.properties?

Comment: local.properties I believe, http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-callback-dev/201206.mbox/%3CCAOBL_k42dx7XO1c_qccWdSovWdiUMQon0oz2uXzfCkao7BDvwg@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: I put it in ant.properties it seemed to work. local.properties wouldn't work on our build machines